# TPL Dataflow, BroadcastBlock to BatchBlocks

Tags: c#, concurrency, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I have a problem connecting `BroadcastBlock(s)` to `BatchBlocks`. The scenario is that the sources are `BroadcastBlocks`, and recipients are `BatchBlocks`.

In the simplified code below, only one of the supplemental action blocks executes. I even set the batchSize for each `BatchBlock` to **1** to illustrate the problem.

Setting Greedy to "true" would make the 2 `ActionBlocks` execute, but that's not what I want as it will cause the `BatchBlock` to proceed even if it's not complete yet. Any ideas?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // My possible sources are BroadcastBlocks. Could be more
        var source1 = new BroadcastBlock<int>(z => z);

        // batch 1
        // can be many potential sources, one for now
        // I want all sources to arrive first before proceeding
        var batch1 = new BatchBlock<int>(1, new GroupingDataflowBlockOptions() { Greedy = false }); 
        var batch1Action = new ActionBlock<int[]>(arr =>
        {
            // this does not run sometimes
            Console.WriteLine("Received from batch 1 block!");
            foreach (var item in arr)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Received {0}", item);
            }
        });

        batch1.LinkTo(batch1Action, new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true });

        // batch 2
        // can be many potential sources, one for now
        // I want all sources to arrive first before proceeding
        var batch2 = new BatchBlock<int>(1, new GroupingDataflowBlockOptions() { Greedy = false  });
        var batch2Action = new ActionBlock<int[]>(arr =>
        {
            // this does not run sometimes
            Console.WriteLine("Received from batch 2 block!");
            foreach (var item in arr)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Received {0}", item);
            }
        });
        batch2.LinkTo(batch2Action, new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true });

        // connect source(s)
        source1.LinkTo(batch1, new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true });
        source1.LinkTo(batch2, new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true });

        // fire
        source1.SendAsync(3);

        Task.WaitAll(new Task[] { batch1Action.Completion, batch2Action.Completion }); ;

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that setting `Greedy` to `true` *is* the right solution. It won't cause smaller batches to be created, if that's what you're worrying about.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a flaw in the internal mechanism of the TPL Dataflow library that supports the non-greedy functionality. What happens is that a `BatchBlock` configured as non-greedy will [`Postpone`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowmessagestatus#fields) all offered messages from linked blocks, instead of accepting them. It keeps an internal queue with the messages it has postponed, and when their number reaches its [`BatchSize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.batchblock-1.batchsize) configuration it attempts to consume the postponed messages, and if successful it propagates them downstream as expected. The problem is that the source blocks like the `BroadcastBlock` and the `BufferBlock` will stop offering more messages to a block that has postponed a previously offered message, until it has consumed this single message. The combination of these two behaviors results to a deadlock. No progress forward can be made, because the `BatchBlock` waits for more messages to be offered before consuming the postponed, and the `BroadcastBlock` waits for the postponed messages to be consumed before offering more messages...

This scenario occurs only with `BatchSize` larger than one (which is the typical configuration for this block).

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/r1rM7s) is a demonstration of this problem. As source it is used the more common `BufferBlock` instead of a `BroadcastBlock`. 10 messages are posted to a three-block pipeline, and the expected behavior is for the messages to flow through the pipeline to the last block. In reality nothing happens, and all messages remain stuck in the first block.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;

public static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var bufferBlock = new BufferBlock<int>();

        var batchBlock = new BatchBlock<int>(batchSize: 2,
            new GroupingDataflowBlockOptions() { Greedy = false });

        var actionBlock = new ActionBlock<int[]>(batch =>
            Console.WriteLine($"Received: {String.Join(", ", batch)}"));

        bufferBlock.LinkTo(batchBlock,
            new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true });

        batchBlock.LinkTo(actionBlock,
            new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true });

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            var accepted = bufferBlock.Post(i);
            Console.WriteLine(
                $"bufferBlock.Post({i}) {(accepted ? "accepted" : "rejected")}");
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

        bufferBlock.Complete();
        actionBlock.Completion.Wait(millisecondsTimeout: 1000);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine($"bufferBlock.Completion: {bufferBlock.Completion.Status}");
        Console.WriteLine($"batchBlock.Completion:  {batchBlock.Completion.Status}");
        Console.WriteLine($"actionBlock.Completion: {actionBlock.Completion.Status}");
        Console.WriteLine($"bufferBlock.Count: {bufferBlock.Count}");
    }
}
```

Output:

```xml
bufferBlock.Post(1) accepted
bufferBlock.Post(2) accepted
bufferBlock.Post(3) accepted
bufferBlock.Post(4) accepted
bufferBlock.Post(5) accepted
bufferBlock.Post(6) accepted
bufferBlock.Post(7) accepted
bufferBlock.Post(8) accepted
bufferBlock.Post(9) accepted
bufferBlock.Post(10) accepted

bufferBlock.Completion: WaitingForActivation
batchBlock.Completion:  WaitingForActivation
actionBlock.Completion: WaitingForActivation
bufferBlock.Count: 10
```

My guess is that the internal [offer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.itargetblock-1.offermessage)-[consume](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.isourceblock-1.consumemessage)-[reserve](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.isourceblock-1.reservemessage)-[release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.isourceblock-1.releasereservation) mechanism has been tuned for maximum efficiency at supporting the [`BoundedCapacity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblockoptions.boundedcapacity) functionality, which is critical for many applications, and the rarely used `Greedy = false` functionality was left non-thoroughly tested.

The good news is that in your case you don't really need to set the `Greedy` to `false`. A `BatchBlock` in the default greedy mode will not propagate less messages than the configured `BatchSize`, unless it has been marked as completed and it propagates any leftover messages, or you manually call its [`TriggerBatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.batchblock-1.triggerbatch) method at any arbitrary moment. The intended usage of the non-greedy configuration is for preventing resource starvation in [complex graph scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-use-joinblock-to-read-data-from-multiple-sources#example), with multiple dependencies between blocks.